# Good way of looping PHP SQL queries?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys i just wanna ask what's the proper way of handling multiple sql queries just like this one

```
$arr = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO table_column ('column1') VALUES (?)";
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($arr); $i++){
        $stmt= $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(1,  $arr[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

It currently works as is but people suggested on avoiding looping with sql queries as it might hammer the database, is there any other way i can do this?

Comment: You can move your  `$stmt= $conn->prepare($sql);` line **before** the loop

Comment: You can [insert multiple rows into a table using a single INSERT statement](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-statement.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can insert multiple values with one SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO table_column ('column1')
VALUES
    ('value1'),
    ('value2'),
    ...
    ('value5');
```

So a better method would be to loop over your array of entries and append them to a single SQL query string. Then you only have to execute it once.

Comment: Yes, good suggestion. But one certainly should _not_ "append all values to a single SQL query string"! The OP uses prepared statements in combination with parameter binding. Most likely there is a reason for that, so most likely the values are _not_ literally coded inside the application (as shown here in the code demonstration), but are of dynamic, client provided manner. In such situation parameter binding is a necessary requirement.

Comment: Instead a placeholder string should be concatenated and used together with an array of values with the same number of entries.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).